# Question about Tensorflow flags: `--enable_batching` vs `--tensorflow_intra_op_parallelism` and `--tensorflow_inter_op_parallelism`

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

In the comment about [--platform_config_file](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L157-L161), it says, if `--platform_config_file` present, then `--enable_batching=true` will be ignored

At the same time, `tensorflow_intra_op_parallelism` and `tensorflow_inter_op_parallelism` can be defined within `--platform_config_file`

if I don't use `--platform_config_file` flag, and directly set those two values via [`--tensorflow_intra_op_parallelism` and `--tensorflow_inter_op_parallelism` flag](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L141-L152), then would `--enable_batching` flag also get ignored?

========

Update:

Found the answer https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/836
Basically when providing `--platform_config_file`, then the batching configs should be included in the platform_config_file if needed

Answer (score 0):

From the update in question:

> Found the answer https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/836.
>
> Basically when providing `--platform_config_file`, then the `batching configs` should be included in the `platform_config_file` if needed
> (paraphrased from jia and chrisolston).